# MsBuild vs dotnet build

Tags: c#, .net, msbuild, dotnet-build

When have I to use one or the other one?

I think that for net framework projects I’ve to use msbuild and for .net projects the dot net build but I don’t why

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tools/dotnet-build#msbuild) of `dotnet build` says:

> dotnet build uses MSBuild to build the project

So you needn't worry about the choice, MSBuild is the end of everything. You can use `dotnet build` to build a .Net Framework project.

For the word `MsBuild` I suppose you mean `MSBuild for .Net Framework`, it can't build .Net/.Net Core projects.

Comment: Unfortunately this is not the case. I have run into many situations where Visual Studio MSBuild compiled successfully, but then dotnet build failed when running on build agents.

Comment: I think those're mostly issues of environmental settings. Or are you saying dotnet build does not use MSBuild? Also as I mentioned, there are 2 kinds of MSBuild. If you run msbuild from the developer command promopt, you will use msbuild for .net framework.

Comment: For those coming along later finding this confusing: `dotnet build` targets .NET Core/5+ and can only build projects using the new project system; it does not support building .NET Framework(or "Classic" as some MS sites are referring to it now). MSBuild.exe targets .NET Framework and is capable of building both new and old style projects targeting .NET Core/5+ and .NET Framework, provided the right SDKs/Workloads/Targeting Packs are installed. Besides "Classic" support, Task extension assemblies loaded by a project must target a compatible framework and references for the cli tool being used.

Comment: @shingo No, it is not environment related. In many instances I have compiled using msbuild on my local machine, which succeeded and then I ran dotnet build from command line and it failed. Same machine, same settings, same project. I don't know what is causing this difference, but occasionally this happens.